# php to keep prompting for input and storing responses

Tags: php

I am not sure what this is called  exactly but I found a php script which i would like to understand how it works and build something similar.

Basically, the user needs to enter some information into a box and then has the option to add another response or to finish. Each response is stored in a seperate string variable.

You can find a work sample from a site I found here:
http://www.claushc.dk/ssl/pkcs7create.php

In the above example the site will only work if you paste in ssl certificate data - you can use the following certificate to test with:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Of course this idea doesn't necessarily need to be used with certificate but I just want to know how the php script can hold the string whilst wait for another input from the user and keep storing input without losing the previous input..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the HTML source (after putting in a few certificates), it's obvious. They include the given input in an hidden input in their response, offering the same input to perform the same trick.

Obviously this can also be done using sessions; a database or some filesystem calls

Comment: thanks Sjon. I think I understand. They post the data back in a hidden input field and then in php they check if input field name isset for data1..2..3.4.. and post it back each time - interesting idea.

Comment: I would not need to store the data permanently so i think database is overkill but would be interested to learn more about how sessions would work in this context

Comment: PHP has this pretty well documented; have a look at [this basic example](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php), it should get you started

Comment: i had a look and watching some tutorial videos now but its not clear how to  pass the same input field to different session variables, if that makes sense i.e.Lets say i have a form with one field with name "data" - my php to store the value would be **$_SESSION['data'] = $_POST['data'];** but what happens if i submit the form again - will it not overwrite the original session variable?

Comment: you already answered my original question so i am happy to open a new question on this topic

Comment: I'd do that if I were you :)